# wp7 - stream creating issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ssh, scp

I am trying to make my app save pictures from remote host via *SSH and SCP* and I need to create an empty Stream variable to full it with ScpClient.Download(string filename, **Stream destination**) method to use it later. Is there any way to do that? I tried:

```
        Stream downloadStream = new MemoryStream();

        scpClient.Connect();
        scpClient.Download("remoteFilename", downloadStream);

        MediaLibrary localLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        localLibrary.SavePicture("localFilename", downloadStream);

        MessageBox.Show("Success!", "Result", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

I am getting unknown exception or the app just quits. Maybe there is a way to pass the image throw the **IsolatedStorage**? I am using **Renci.SshNet** library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your code in a try ... catch block

```
        try
        {
            // your stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Then add your exception details to your question, you'd get more help from people in here.